# Step-by-Step Construction of Gene Co-expression Networks from High-Throughput Arabidopsis RNA Sequencing Data

Tags: r, rna-seq

I am following the tutorial [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29525965/) to learn how to process raw RNA-seq data and get gene read counts. I've had no issues until I got to step 3.9, "Assignment of RNA-Seq Reads to Genes." Here, the authors run the command

```
fc0 <- featureCounts(sam.list, annot.ext = 
"Ara-port11_GFF3_genes_transposons.201606.gtf", allowMultiOverlap = T, isPairedEnd = F, 
nthreads = 2, strandSpecific = 0, isGTFAnnotationFile = T)
```

I ran the same command except I set isGTFAnnotationFile = F because I couldn't find the gtf file, so I used the gff file `TAIR10_GFF3_genes_transposons.gff` instead, downloaded from [here](https://www.arabidopsis.org/download/index-auto.jsp?dir=%2Fdownload_files%2FGenes%2FTAIR10_genome_release%2FTAIR10_gff3) (they mentioned that using gtf only speeds up the process but that you can still do this using gff). I'm not sure if this is what is causing the issue, but the error I get is:

```
Error: Line 1 contains a format error. The expected annotation format is SAF.
Error in featureCounts(sam.list, annot.ext = "TAIR10_GFF3_genes_transposons.gff",  : 
  No counts were generated.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question @AnIgnorantWanderer please consider "Accepting" your answer below because it helps with site statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer from @an-ignorant-wanderer, converted from [comment](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):*

I ended up using the annotation file from https://support.illumina.com/sequencing/sequencing_software/igenome.html and it worked.

*[Please update/improve this answer if possible]*